# Compile error with boost 1.71.0 on Centos7

Tags: c++, boost, centos7

On Centos7 with the default gcc compiler (version 4.8.5) I have build boost 1.71.0 64bit from scratch. No problems occurred during the build; everything works fine.
When I try to compile a source which uses boost (in my case boost/thread.hpp), I get a compile error:

```
boost/bind/storage.hpp:44:40: error: macro "accept" requires 3 arguments, but only 1 given

     template<class V> void accept(V & v) const
                                        ^
```

The compiler switches are:

`g++ -c -Wall -Wno-error -fPIC -g -O0 -D WITH_XXTGNOME_TRACE -D DEBUG -D_PTHREADS=1 -D_REENTRANT=1   -m64 -std=gnu++11`

followed by the include paths.

The same source compiles without errors using VS 2017. Does somebody has any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: works on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/CUxVvZ), please provide a [mre]. You (or some other library you've included) probably defined a macro called `accept` which is breaking boost, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/qAJBQw

Comment: That was the solution! There is another makro with the same name defined, which is  not used in Windows (#ifndef _WIN32 ...). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a macro called `accept` that takes 3 parameters. This will cause problems for any use of the name `accept` for variable names, function names, method names, class names etc.

If you must use Macros make sure the have a globally unique name, one convention is to use all uppercase letters for macro names, you should also prefix your names with something unique. For example:

```
#define MY_LIB_NAME_ACCEPT(a, b, c)
```

Is much less likely to conflict with third party code than `#define accept`.